# Autocomplete does not load data correctly

Tags: java, methods, jtextfield

I have a problem with the following code, if filtered data appears to me, but it only filters it when the jframe starts, but not when I add a new one, I have to close the jframe and reopen it so that it just recognizes that data. I put the data in .txt

```
String barrapro = File.separator;
String ubicacionpro = System.getProperty("user.dir")+barra+"Procesador"+barra;

File contenedorpro = new File(ubicacionpro);
File [] procesadorlistado = contenedorpro.listFiles();

public TextAutoCompleter AutocompletarProcesador;

public Registrar() {
    initComponents();
    setLocationRelativeTo(this);
    AutocompleterReg();

    public void AutocompleterReg() {
        AutocompletarProcesador = new TextAutoCompleter(TProcesador1);
        for (int i = 0; i < procesadorlistado.length; i++) {
            AutocompletarProcesador.addItem(procesadorlistado[i].getName().replace(".procesador", ""));
        }
    }
```

I saw in some forums that use repaint and but I only want that when one is modified in real time the filtering is updated, it does but it continues showing the data that was already deleted until I close the jframe and reopen it, I also tried to do it with timer but if I do that, it won't let me select as if it were google search, pressing the down arrow key to select the result I want.

[video_recording.mp4](https://files.catbox.moe/tf2cg7.mp4)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're experiencing is likely due to the fact that the list of files in the "Procesador" directory is only being read once, when the Registrar JFrame is first created. When a new file is added to the directory, the program doesn't know to refresh the list of files.

One way to fix this would be to update the list of files in the directory and repopulate the TextAutoCompleter every time the JFrame is made visible. You can do this by overriding the setVisible() method of the JFrame and updating the list of files and the TextAutoCompleter inside of it.